# List of footnotes in latex

Tags: list, latex, footnotes

I was wondering if I'll have the option to add something like \listoffootnotes in my document like I can use \listoffigures or tables...

Anyone knows how?

Comment: Why would you want a list of footnotes?

Comment: And why not? It deppends on how do you use it. I have different info in my footnotes and my bib. I just need a list of them and the page where they are.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the example and it worked very well. Here is what I've done:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

%% Footnotes-Listing %%
\newcommand{\listfootnotesname}{List of Footnotes}% 'List of Footnotes' title 
\newlistof[chapter]{footnotes}{fnt}{\listfootnotesname}% New 'List of...' for footnotes 
\let\oldfootnote\footnote % Save the old \footnote{...} command 
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{% Redefine the new footnote to also add 'List of Footnote' entries. 
    \refstepcounter{footnotes}% Add and step a reference to the footnote/counter. 
    \oldfootnote{#1}% Make a regular footnote. 
    \addcontentsline{fnt}{footnotes}{\protect 
\numberline{\thefootnotes}#1}% Add the 'List of...' entry. 
}
```

After tha I could use the command ***\listoffootnotes***:
[image]

The *tocloft*-Package is Part of [Texlive-Extra](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/TeXLivePackages#texlive-latex-extra).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but from what I gather it should be possible to accomplish what you need using the tocloft package. See chapter 2.4 in the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) for more details on creating custom lists.

[Here is an example](http://groups.google.de/group/latexusersgroup/msg/ac3b1be0d80e7b88) on how it can be done.

Comment: I have the package and the exmaple doesn't work for me. I tried to add it to my code, and neither :/ But that's what I need!!

Comment: Do you mind sharing what doesn't work ? Perhaps we could find the answer to that.

Comment: I mean that package doesn't do what it supposed to do. I don't know where the problem is because I have the package and I just copy/paste.